# Django: constrain foreign key to only rows with the same id

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, django-models

For a Django project, I got two models:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    child = models.ForeignKey('children.Child', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

And the following:

```
class Child(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

What I want is that `User.child` can only be set to an entity that has `child.user_id = user.id`, with a constraint preferably. Is this possible? If it matters, I am using PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you looking for a [one-to-one relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/)?

- `user` in `Child` can only be set to one `User`.
- `child` in `User` can also only be set to one `Child`.
- You want `user` in `Child` and `child` in `User` to point to each other.

This is exactly what a one-to-one relationship is. The following code is even simpler than your current one and it enforces the constraint at the database level:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    # The relationship only needs to be defined in one of the models
    pass

class Child(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

If there are finer points you need to cover (eg. if there are situations in which you would need the relationship to be defined in one direction but not in the other), then please clarify the use case.